# Sourcing R script stored in AWS S3

Tags: r, amazon-s3

I'm developing script that will be used by a web application to generate insights. In a local machine I would be able to split out script so that I can use source() to execute them as required in subsequent tasks. A simplified example as follows:

- script 1: Calculate mortgage cash flows
- script 2: Calculate the net
  cash flows of the output in script 1

This approach enables me to only need to maintain script 1 once, since script 2 refers to script 1 directly. The issue I'm having is that I can't get source() to work on R scripts I have uploaded to the S3 bucket. The research I've done thus far has led me to think that the aws.s3 package is the tool that I need, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have been able to accomplish the following:

```
url<- 'https://s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/[bucket name]/[bucket sub-folder]/rscript.R'

Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "My access key",
       "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "My secret access key",
       "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "ca-central-1")

get_bucket(bucket= '[bucket name]')
```

If I run get_bucket, I can see that it's picking up the name of the file within my bucket and I'm able to access the S3 folder. But I can't figure out how to pull the rscript.R file

Essentially, I'd like to be able to execute

```
source(rscript.R)
```

Other Potential Option: I looked through the Shiny documentation and my interpretation is that it's intended for interactive web graphics. If Shiny would actually be suitable for my issue, please let me know.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `aws s3 cp` or `sync`?

Comment: I believe it would be cp, since I'm only trying to access a single file in my bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cloudyr::s3source()`.

From the [README](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3):

> `s3source()` sources an R script directly from S3

---

In your case, something like this...

```
s3source(object = "rscript.R", bucket = get_bucket('[bucket name]'), echo = TRUE)
```

Comment: Didn't work at first but then I read through the README and once I installed it using # latest stable version
install.packages("aws.s3", repos = c("cloudyr" = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat")) it worked

Comment: Figured out how to make it work with a sub-folder. /[sub-folder]/rscript.R in the object field. Thanks again!

Comment: fwiw it seems this function is just a wrapper to download the script and then run `source`: https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/blob/master/R/s3source.R